# How do I start Octave GUI from zip file install

Tags: octave

I downloaded windows 32 zip file version of [Octave from here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/#install)

I do not want to use the installer to fully install Octave and would prefer to use it through the zip file extraction

I can start octave in the command line from

```
octave-4.4.1-w32\octave-4.4.1-w32\bin\octave.bat
```

This gives me the octave interpreter in the Windows cmd prompt, but I thought octave had it's own GUI and IDE similar to matlab

How do I start this IDE from the zip file install version of octave? Is the GUI IDE present in the zip file version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Octave for Microsoft Windows](https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows)
says (paraphrased):

> For the zip archives, the user should extract the file content to a
>   directory on the harddrive (such as `C:\Octave`). Manual shortcuts can
>   then be created to either the `octave.bat` or `octave.vbs` files in the
>   main installation directory.
>
> Note that starting with Octave 4.4.0, the shortcuts will no longer
>   start the graphical user interface by default. The user needs to add
>   `--force-gui` to any manual shortcuts to start Octave with the GUI. 
>   (Right-click on the shortcut, select Properties, and add `--force-gui`
>   to the end of the Target field.)

For Visual flow see below screenshots:

1. [Create shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7LVE.png)
2. Move it to your desired location. 
   (Here I moved it to where a file is extracted.)
3. [Right-click on shortcut and click on "Properties".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqXpI.png)
4. [Finally add `--force-gui` in the "Target" field and click "OK".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHbcf.png) 
   That's it. 
   Now open the shortcut and you'll be able to run Octave in the GUI.